# lib pywhatkit can't send slash(bar) '/' in whatsapp

Tags: python, whatsapp

I want to be able to send a link with pywhatkit on whatsapp, but when typing whenever it reaches the '/' it stops typing in the text box and starts typing in the object to look for other contacts, does anyone know how to solve this?

Able to send link on whatsapp.

[image]

my code:

```
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_to_group_instantly('my_group_code', url)

#my_group_code is group invitation code
#url is the variable that contains the link
```

it goes up to the part of searching for contacts after the first slash '/' is typed.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I've already done the test of leaving only one slash '/', and the problem continues to occur, it goes up to the part of searching for contacts after the first slash '/' is typed.

Comment: have you tried passing an r-string?

Comment: @СергейКох I've tried it and it didn't work, from what I saw it's something related to my computer, I tested it on another different computer and it worked perfect without any modifications, I believe it could be something related to the windows layout, I tested other layoutyt's that didn't work, the English layout it replaces the ':' with '?' . I still haven't found a solution, I've tried many things, but nothing seems to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it's a whats app web shortcut that makes this happen when the library uses the same shortcut to type the slash '/', I didn't find a solution, but in a palliative way, I created a virtual machine with a layout all in English, inside it works perfectly.

Updating, on my machine now it worked, leave the windows keyboard layout with English United States US standard.